# График справа от cgridview?

Tags: php, css, yii

Справа от `GridView` хочу изобразить график с помощью `HighchartsWidget`. У грида ставлю

```
'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 80%'),
```

Как заставить график рисоваться не после таблицы, а в той же строке? Чую, что проблема в css `GridView`, так как простой текст тоже отображается строго ниже таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо обернуть грид в див. Грид сам растянется по ширине дива. Например так

```
<style>
.container { overflow: hidden; clear: both; width: 100%; }
.container .left, .columns .right { float: left; }
.container .left { width: 80%; }
.container .right { width: 20%; }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left"><?php $this->widget('CGridView'/* тут вызываем грид */); ?></div>
  <div class="right"><!-- тут вызываем график --></div>
</div>
```